# Z-Index issues with DropDown Menu

Tags: html, css

When I hover over a menu, the menu li beneath is visible. It could be the div, but not sure. When I change to static and relative, they just shift down
Here is my site http://ocart.site/opencart/

```
#menu > ul > li > div {
position: relative;
z-index: 5;
```

I have tried adding relative and a higher z-index, with no joy

Comment: Please post your code here, see how to create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the following CSS rules:

```
#menu > ul > li {
    z-index: auto;
}

#menu > ul > li > a {
    z-index: auto;
}

#menu > ul > li > div {
    z-index: auto;
}

#menu > ul > li:hover > div {
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Because you also define z-indexes on top level elements, the z-index which you refer to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

`#menu > ul > li` and  `#menu > ul > li`

remove z-index declaration from them

as other answer suggests , you can give them `auto` value but its by default , so just remove it